# English idiom for only being able to act in the way you were raised

Tags: phrase-requests, british-english, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an English (UK) idiom which I think might be similar to "I can only follow my roots" and means that I can only act in the way I was raised.

Comment: Like father, like son.  The apple doesn't fall very far from the tree.

Comment: A leopard can't change his spots.

Answer (score 3):

"As the twig is bent, so grows the tree." It's based on a bit of [Pope](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803110350386):

> 'Tis education forms the common mind,
>   Just as the twig is bent the tree's inclined

The saying is used in the US.  I  assume, given its source, that is also used in the UK.

Comment: I forgot to mention "The child is father of the man," also from an English poet. (William Wordsworth, in "My Heart Leaps Up.")  https://www.thoughtco.com/child-is-the-father-of-man-3975052

Comment: I have never heard it used in my region of the UK but that's not to say other dialects don't.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to phrase In question one can say :

> I remember my roots./I can’t [won’t]  forget my roots./I remember where I came from.

Numerous examples of above online and I’m not sure if there is a clear original source.  On a similar vein, I like this quote:

> I remember my mother's prayers and they have always followed me. They have clung to me all my life.
>   Abraham Lincoln.
>    [brainyquote.com](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/abraham_lincoln_145909?src=t_remember)

Answer (score 1):

Wolfgang Mieder, *A Dictionary of American Proverbs* (1992) identifies multiple variants of the following proverb, which may be on point:

> **What is bred in the bone will come out in the flesh.**

Mieder says that this expression goes back to circa 1290, with a first recorded North American occurrence in 1637. The idea is that what is most deeply embedded in a person or thing will find expression closer to the surface as well.